# how to find the leading parent to a thread via postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find the parent to multiple rows of data. Let's say I have three records the first record is the parent (record #123). The second record (record #945) which was a reply to the first has a parent of #123. However, the third record (record #567), which was a reply to the second message, has a parent of 945. I want the parent to show 123 and not 945. (Ultimately I want to answer how many threads are typically on a message) See example chart below. Any help of how to do this via postgresql would be extremely appreciated.

```
header_id   id   parent   FIELD_NEEDED
87654311    123  null       123
87654311    945  123        123
87654311    567  945        123
87654311    691  123        123
87654311    876  null       876
87654311    721  null       721
87654311    108  721        721
87654311    236  108        721
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q(header_id, id ,parent,field_needed, root, pp) 
as (
    select header_id,id ,parent,field_needed,id as root, parent pp
    from table1 t
    union all
    select q.header_id,q.id ,q.parent,q.field_needed,t.id, t.parent
    from q
    join table1 t 
    on t.id = q.pp
)
select header_id, id ,parent,field_needed, root
from q
where pp is null
```

Comment: How are you calculating 'field_needed'?